# Hashing multiple byte[]'s together into a single hash with C#?

Tags: c#, hash

I have three fields: `string Title`, `byte[] Body`, and `byte[] Data`, from which I want to calculate a single hash as a check to be sure they haven't been tampered with or corrupted.

In Python, I can use `md5.update()` a few times in succession to perform this.  But I can't find similar capability in C#.  To use MD5.ComputeHash() I'd need to copy all my sources into a single byte[], which is a step I'd like to avoid.

How can I hash it all together into one hash without having to copy the data into a temporary buffer?

Comment: Why not use the temp variable?

Comment: And BTW, I guess python creates a single bytes array under the hood...

Comment: You know that MD5 is broken, right? You say that you are using the hash to detect tampering, but it is computationally feasible for the attacker to tamper with the document without changing the hash. You should be using SHA256 or some other hash algorithm that does not have known collision-resistance problems.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Almost all hash algorithms are designed in a way that they can successively be fed with the data in multiple blocks. The result is the same as if the whole data was hashed at once.

Create an instance of e.g. [MD5CryptoServiceProvider](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.md5cryptoserviceprovider.aspx) and call the [TransformBlock Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.hashalgorithm.transformblock.aspx) for each block and the [TransformFinalBlock Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.hashalgorithm.transformfinalblock.aspx) for the last block:

```
MD5 md5 = new MD5CryptoServiceProvider();

// For each block:
md5.TransformBlock(block, 0, block.Length, block, 0);

// For last block:
md5.TransformFinalBlock(block, 0, block.Length);

// Get the hash code
byte[] hash = md5.Hash;
```

Comment: Seems like a mix of languages?

Comment: Can you provide a code example?  I see that method but its use eludes me.  How do I avoid it overwriting the previous output, for instance?

Comment: Transform(Final)Block essentially works the same way as update, i.e. it updates the internal state of the MD5 instance with the new data. I've added an example (untested though).

Comment: If lenght of block is not multiple of block size, TransfomFinalBlock() method will destroy context. Answer about IncrementalHash is correct, it will keep context after hash calculation for any data length

Answer (score 24):

There is also solution in .Net Standard and .Net Core using [IncrementalHash](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.cryptography.incrementalhash.createhash?view=net-5.0)

```
IncrementalHash sha256 = IncrementalHash.CreateHash(HashAlgorithmName.SHA256)

// For each block:
sha256.AppendData(block);

// Get the hash code
byte[] hash = sha256.GetHashAndReset();
```

As pointed out by Eric Lippert, also use `SHA256` instead of `md5` for better collision resistence.

Answer (score 0):

Using plain .NET, I don't think there is a way to update and MD5 hash. However, Windows has an [MD5Update](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb432359%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) function defined in crypt.dll. You could use Interop to leverage this I suppose.

Otherwise, there is an implementation of a PHP equivalent in .NET c#, located here on SO: [Problem porting PHP crypt() function to C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/855103/problem-porting-php-crypt-function-to-c)

PS: I would definitely go for the combined temp variable solution :-)

Answer (score 0):

Calling the ComputeHash function on three different values is going to create three different byte array results. Those results will then have to be combined in some way to produce a single hash. There is no way around this fact. It will create three new objects in the heap. It will compute a hash (a fairly slow operation) three times instead of just one.

I think the most performant way to do what you want is to just go ahead and copy your source values into a single byte array and take the hash of that.

You don't say why you want to avoid this approach. I think it wins in terms of simplicity and maintainability. It is the self-documenting, obvious approach. It is the most performant method. I don't really see a down-side.

Comment: The downside is if you had a 1GB file then you'd load that 1GB byte array into memory instead of buffering it for increased performance..

Answer (score -1):

You have to combine them all in a single variable and then calculate the MD5 Hash. I don't see any shortcut there.

You see, most of solutions proposed here just try either to run multiple commands on the same line ("one liners") or implement something to "under the hood" combine your fields and then Hash...

Answer (score -1):

you can create a Hash over the Hash values.

```
MD5 md5 =  System.Security.Cryptography.MD5.Create();
byte[] totalHash= md5.ComputeHash(md5.ComputeHash(part1).Concat(md5t.computeHash(part2)));
```

doesnt create a copy of the byte array but hashes a concatenation of the hashes.

Comment: +1: Dunno why you got -1'd, it's a reasonable solution IMO (though @dtb's is better :) ).

Comment: just asked myself why i got the -1. But i agree that dtb's is better :-)

Comment: this reduces the crypto strength (on an already weakened MD5), potentially significantly so is to be avoided. (not that I -1'd but I would assume that was the reason). I don't believe it's anywhere near so horrid as Guffa's suggestion but it's not a good idea to roll your own crypto in this way (even if the building blocks are good)

Comment: how exactly is it reducing the crypto strength? (i dont deny that it does, just wondering). if we assume that MD5 would be safe (no collisions reconstructable) it doesnt really matter how often i run the algorithm over its own produced hash, it wont get more secure, but neither less?

Comment: because someone no longer needs to find a collision in XYZ, they need to find a collision in either X, Y, Z or X'Y'Z (where  V' is hash(V)).

Comment: It's something else. Hash of concatenation of hashes gives entirely different result than hash of concatenated data.