# C# Hashing multiple byte array blocks

Tags: c#, hash, md5

I am trying to hash a file by reading 1024 bytes from a FileStream in a loop and using TransformBlock function. I need this to understand the mechanics of hashing multiple byte arrays into one hash. This would allow me to hash not only files, but also folders. I used this stackoverflow question: [Hashing multiple byte[]'s together into a single hash with C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5805106/hashing-multiple-bytes-together-into-a-single-hash-with-c) and this msdn example: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.hashalgorithm.transformblock.aspx

Here is the code I have now:

```
public static byte[] createFileMD5(string path){
    MD5 md5 = MD5.Create();
    FileStream fs = File.OpenRead(path);
    byte[] buf = new byte[1024];
    byte[] newbuf = new byte[1024];

    int num; int newnum;

    num = fs.Read(buf,0,buf.Length);
    while ((newnum = fs.Read(newbuf, 0, newbuf.Length))>0)
    {
        md5.TransformBlock(buf, 0, buf.Length, buf, 0);
        num = newnum;
        buf = newbuf;
    }

    md5.TransformFinalBlock(buf, 0, num);

    return md5.Hash;
}
```

Unfortunately the hash which it calculates doesnt correspond to the one which I calculated using fciv.

Just to be sure: hexing algorithm which I use on the returned byte array:

```
    public static string byteArrayToString(byte[] ba)
    {
        StringBuilder hex = new StringBuilder(ba.Length * 2);
        foreach (byte b in ba)
            hex.AppendFormat("{0:x2}", b);
        return hex.ToString();
    }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The length you pass to `TransformBlock` is wrong for the last block (unless the file size is a multiple of the buffer size). You need to pass the actual number of bytes read from the file:

```
md5.TransformBlock(buf, 0, newnum, buf, 0);
```

Also, I'm not sure why you use `newbuf`... the original buffer is used only for the first block, then you use `newbuf` for all subsequent blocks. There is no reason to use a second buffer here. For reference, here's the code I use to compute the hash of a file:

```
            using (var stream = File.OpenRead(path))
            {
                var md5 = MD5.Create();
                var buffer = new byte[8192];
                int read;
                while ((read = stream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) > 0)
                {
                    md5.TransformBlock(buffer, 0, read, buffer, 0);
                }
                md5.TransformFinalBlock(buffer, 0, 0);

                ...
            }
```

Comment: I thought that I had to use TransformBlock on every block EXCEPT the last one, and use TransformFinalBlock on the last one. It was unclear in the other stackoverflow question:
// For each block:
md5.TransformBlock(block, 0, block.Length, block, 0);

// For last block:
md5.TransformFinalBlock(block, 0, block.Length);

Comment: @black, actually I'm not sure the way I do it would work with all hash algorithms... I know it works for MD5 and SHA1, but perhaps other algorithms require that all blocks passed to TransformBlock have the same size.

Comment: @black: Generally you do `TransformBlock` on every block except the last one. Then you call `TransformFinalBlock` on the last block. However, in a stream of an unknown length, you may not know if the last block has been processed until it is too late. For this reason a properly implemented algorithm is expected to finalise the hash when `TransformFinalBlock` is called with an empty array as in the answer. In an ideal case, however, `TransformFinalBlock` is expected to be called with the last block of data from the stream. **PS:** I tested both ways with MD5 & SHA256 and can confirm it works.