# Computehash any way to achieve the same result when not reading the whole file at once?

Tags: c#, md5

I'm using MD5.ComputeHash to get the MD5 hash value of a whole file. As that is QUITE slow for big files and thus increases the time I need to wait until I can do what I need to do for the big files (copying them to be exact) I wonder if there is a way to do so during the copy process and still get the same result (my guess is no, but I want to make sure there).

Thus for eample for reading the full file at once:

```
using (Stream fileStream....)
{
     using (var stream new BufferedStream(fileStream, 1024*1024)
     {
          MD5 md5 = MD5.Create();
          byte[] checksum = md5Hash.ComputeHash(stream);
          .....
     } 
}
```

The split up version:

```
using (Stream fileStream....)
{
     int currentBlockSize = 0;
     MD5 md5 = MD5.Create();
     byte[] readBuffer = new Byte[....];
     while ((currentBlockSize = sourceStream.Read(readBuffer, 0, readBuffer.Length)) > 0)
     {
          byte[] checksumpart = md5Hash.ComputeHash(readBuffer);
          .....
     } 
}
```

And then adding those parts together.
From what I know about MD5 normally I would say there is no way to make the second version get the same result as the first version BUT I'm not sure exactly how computehash works there in combination with a buffered stream thus my question: IS there any way to make these 2 versions give the same result?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it is possible to update the hash during "chunking" the file. Each chunk is added through TransformBlock and the last one through TransformFinalBlock, which should get you the final hash through the "Hash" property on the md5 instance.

```
MD5 md5 = new MD5CryptoServiceProvider();

// For each block:
md5.TransformBlock(block, 0, block.Length, block, 0);

// For last block:
md5.TransformFinalBlock(block, 0, block.Length);

// Get the hash code
byte[] hash = md5.Hash;
```

Source: [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5805228/1361993)

Answer (score 2):

This is actually standard stuff: use `md5.TransformBlock` in the cycle instead of the .ComputeHash and in the end get the `md5.Hash`:

```
var md5 = new MD5CryptoServiceProvider();

using (Stream fileStream....)
{
     int currentBlockSize = 0; 
     byte[] readBuffer = new Byte[....];
     while ((currentBlockSize = sourceStream.Read(readBuffer, 0, readBuffer.Length)) > 0)
     {
          byte[] checksumpart = md5Hash.ComputeHash(readBuffer);
          md5.TransformBlock(checksumpart, 0, currentBlockSize, null, 0);
     } 
}

md5.TransformFinalBlock(new byte[0], 0, 0);

return md5.Hash;
```