# Is it possible to copy a .NET HashAlgorithm (for repeated incremental hash results)?

Tags: c#, clone, md5, hashalgorithm

I have the following use case:

- Read n bytes from a file
- Compute (MD5) hash for these n bytes
- Read next m bytes from file
- Compute (MD5) hash for the file up to n+m bytes

Incrementally hashing a file isn't the problem, [just call `TransformBlock` and `TransformFinalBlock`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5805228/321013).

The problem is that I need multiple hashes of data that shares its beginning bytes, but after I have called `TransformFinalBlock` to read the `Hash` of the first `n` bytes I cannot continue to hash with the same object and need a new one.

Searching for the problem, I saw that both [Python](https://docs.python.org/2/library/hashlib.html#module-hashlib) as well as [OpenSSL](https://www.openssl.org/docs/crypto/EVP_DigestInit.html#DESCRIPTION) have an option to copy a hashing object for exactly this purpose:

> hash.copy()
>
> Return a copy (“clone”) of the hash object. This **can be used to efficiently compute the digests of strings that share a common initial substring**.

> EVP_MD_CTX_copy_ex() can be used to copy the message digest state from
>   in to out. **This is useful if large amounts of data are to be hashed
>   which only differ in the last few bytes**. out must be initialized
>   before calling this function.

Searching as I may, I can't find anything withing the stock C# [HashAlgorithm](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.hashalgorithm%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) that would allow me to effectively `Clone()` == copy such an object *before* calling its `TransformFinalBlock` method -- and afterwards continue to hash the rest of the data with the clone.

I found a [C# reference implementation for MD5](http://dlaa.me/blog/post/9380245) that could be trivially adapted to support cloning(*) but would strongly prefer to use what is there instead of introducing such a thing into the codebase.

(*) Indeed, as far as I understand, *any* Hashing Algorithm (as opposed to encryption/decryption) I've bothered to check is trivially copyable because all the state such an algorithm has is a form of a digest.

So am I missing something here or does the standard C#/.NET interface in fact not offer a way to copy the hash object?

---

Another data point:

Microsoft's *own* native API for [crypto services](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa380252%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) has a function [`CryptDuplicateHash`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa379919%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), the docs of which state, quote:

> The CryptDuplicateHash function can be used to create separate hashes
>   of two different contents that begin with the same content.

Been around since Windows XP. :-|

---

Note wrt. MD5: The use case is not cryptographically sensitive. Just reliable file checksumming.

Comment: One issue with it not being trivially cloneable, some classes may use native resources or call out to specialized hardware with handles. Those types of classes would not be as easy to clone.

Comment: @Scott - Thanks. Yeah I guess some classes may. Still, those that *don't*, like MD5, should really be cloneable. So there's no way?

Comment: It seems as though if you want even a shallow copy you will have to iterate the whole thing and create it yourself.

Comment: @MartinBa Could you use the return value of TransformFinalBlock (System.Byte[] An array that is a copy of the part of the input that is hashed) to create a copy manually?

Comment: @MartinBa Actually Both [`MD5Cng`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.md5cng%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and [`MD5CryptoServiceProvider`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.md5cryptoserviceprovider%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) both call out to native code. If .NET provided a `MD5Managed` class (Similar to `AesManaged` or `RijndaelManaged`) that fully implemented the algorithm in manged code it might be easy, but you must go to a 3rd party to get that (like the link to the implementation you provided)

Comment: @Scott - I don't see why they shouldn't be trivially cloneable even with a "normal" native resource. Either it hold a native resource in the form of a native sub-object, in which case that one can be trivially cloned as well, or it is even "only" calling some stateless native algorithm, in which case nothing native is to copy. Anyways, just sayin'. Thanks for these infos.

Comment: @Scott - guess what I found: [`CryptDuplicateHash`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa379919%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) ... *Sigh* :-)

Comment: CloneableHash: https://searchcode.com/codesearch/view/14605640/

Comment: @Donal - thanks. That's a useful link. Wrapping the Win32 Crypt* stuff via PInvoke ... how awful ;-)

Comment: @MartinBa I didn't write it! :-)

Comment: @Donal - it *is* really useful to see that others apparently had the same issues and had to wrap the native API. It's just that *I*'d use a C++/CLI project to wrap the native stuff instead of that PInvoke abomination. :-)

Comment: Can you give some details on what the problem is?  Is this file-transfer related?  Is there something producing/uploading the data you're trying to hash?  Do you have control over the code on both sides of the wire?  Maybe there is an alternative approach you can take.

Comment: @scottt732 - The problem is exactly hashing a data stream up to point a and then continue to hash it until the end. The alternative is actually to not use the crappy .NET interface (well crappy at *least* in this regard, IMHO) but rely on one of the other implementations linked to. I justs didn't get to self-answer yet.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*SIGH*

The stock .NET library does not allow this. Sad. Anyways, there are a couple of alternatives:

- [`MD5Managed` pure .NET](http://dlaa.me/blog/post/9380245) ("default" MD5 RSA license)
- [`ClonableHash`](https://searchcode.com/codesearch/view/14605640/) that wraps the MS Crypto API via PInvoke (may need some work extracting that from the `Org.Mentalis` namespace, but the license is permissive)

It is also possible to for example wrap a [C++ implementation](http://www.zedwood.com/article/cpp-md5-function) in a C++/CLI wrapper - preliminary tests have shown that this seems to be way faster than the normal .NET library, but don't take my word on it.

---

Since, I also wrote/adapted a C++ based solution myself: https://github.com/bilbothebaggins/md5cpp

It hasn't gone into production, because the requirements changed, but it was a nice exercise and I like to think it works quite well. (Other than it not being a pure C# implementation.)

Answer (score 4):

I realize this isn't exactly what you are asking for, but if this matches the problem you're trying to solve it's an alternative approach that would give you the same guarantees & similar streaming performance characteristics.  I've used this in the past for a server-to-server file transfer protocol where the sender/receiver weren't always available/reliable.  Granted, I had control over the code on both sides of the wire which I realize you may not.  In that case, please ignore ;-)

My approach was to setup 1 HashAlgorithm that dealt with the entire file and another one for hashing fixed-sized blocks of the file--not rolling hashes (avoids your problem), but standalone hashes.  So imagine a 1034MB (1 GB + 10 MB) file logically split into 32MB blocks.  The sender loaded the file, calling TransformBlock on both the file-level and the block-level HashAlgorithm's at the same time.  When it reached the end of the 32MB, it called TransformFinalBlock on the block-level one, recorded the hash for that block, and reset/created a new HashAlgorithm for the next block.  When it reached the end of the file it called TransformFinalBlock on the file- and block-level hasher.  Now the sender had a 'plan' for the transfer that included filename, file size, file hash, and the offset, length, and hash of each block.

It sent the plan to the receiver, who either allocated space for a new file (file length % block size tells it that the last block is smaller than 32MB) or opened the existing file.  If the file was already there, it ran the same algorithm to compute the hash of the same-sized blocks.  Any mismatches against the plan caused it to ask the sender for those blocks only (this would account for not-yet-transferred blocks/all 0's and corrupt blocks).  It did this (verify, ask for blocks) work in a loop until there was nothing left to ask for.  Then it checked the file-level hash against the plan.  If the file-level hash was invalid but the block-level hashes were all valid, it would probably mean either a hash colission or bad RAM (both extremely rare... I used SHA-512).  This allowed the receiver to recover from incomplete blocks or corrupt blocks with a worst-case-scenario penalty of having to download 1 bad block again, which could be offset by tuning the block size.

Comment: Appreciated. Running two hashes at the same time is certainly a solution if performance is not relevant (or not relevant vs. e.g. file-transfer-speed).

Comment: @MartinBa You could tweak his solution, use chunked hashes but in the input for the next chunk you concat the output of the previous chunk. When you want to "copy" the hash all you need to do is restart at the same offset in the other file and seed it with the output from the previous chunk in the first file. Basically doing a similar algorithm to [CBC Encryption Mode](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_cipher_mode_of_operation#Cipher-block_chaining_.28CBC.29) but concating the input instead of XORing it.

Comment: The overhead isn't bad.  I was reading the file 32kb/64kb bytes at-a-time into a buffer.  Both instances processed the same byte[] buffer, so there's no disk I/O penalty for hashing twice.  The I/O is where most of the speed penalty comes from.