# How to openssl passwd -1 in C# against MySQL

Tags: c#, mysql, openssl, md5

I am making one extension for iRedMail server, I want to add new user using C# code.
IrerdMail holding users inside MySQL database, passwords of users are encrypted using openssl (MD5).
When I look at iRedMail api for creating users there is line of code inside bash script:

```
openssl passwd -1 passwordToBeEncrpted
```

That command inside terminal return me MD5 string, If I copy that string to my app and execute insert command against MySQL table hosted on mail-server created user works OK.
What will be proper way to generate MD5 from user password so I can insert that to MySQL database ?
My app running on other server beside iRedMAil, Is it obligatory to MD5 be created on the same machine ?
I am considering calling SSH command from C# code , Is there free .NET library which can reuse output stings from SSH as variables ?
Can this be done using something like UDF like in MSSQL server. I know how I cloud call command app from MSSQL does something like that exist at MySQL - CentoOS combination.

Answer (score 1):

Just an idea: instead of trying to call openssl (which users will have to install, or you have to include in your installation procedure) with all the associated hassle it might be preferable to just port over [the original C source for crypt](http://www.freebsd.org/cgi/cvsweb.cgi/~checkout~/src/lib/libcrypt/crypt.c?rev=1.2).

This will take you some time to get right, but IMO your program will be a lot simpler, more robust and more compact to install.

EDIT: have a look at this question here on SO: [Problem porting PHP crypt() function to C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/855103/problem-porting-php-crypt-function-to-c-sharp) - the code he wrote was meant to be compatible with BSD crypt, so it might be just what you need..  I just tested it in Visual Studio 2010 and compared to the output of openssl on a Linux box here, and the outputs match.

Answer (score 1):

My open-source library [CryptSharp](http://www.zer7.com/software/cryptsharp) (since 2.0) supports MD5 crypt. The syntax is:

```
string cryptedPassword = Crypter.MD5.Crypt("password");
```

Should do what you need.

James