# Password encrypt in vb.net

Tags: vb.net

Encrypting passwords in VB.net

I want to encrypt the password in VB.NET the way it's done in PHP as following:
this is my php code:

```
$encriptar = crypt($_POST["Password"], '$2a$07$asxx54ahjppf45sd87a5a4dDDGsystemdev$');
```

so I want the password ecrypted in vb.net to be same ecripted in PHP

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [C# emulating php crypt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32454716/c-sharp-emulating-php-crypt)

Answer (score 0):

It's a non-trivial matter to implement since there's no built-in Unix-password-hash function such as crypt() in .NET . However, there seems to be someone who's done a lot of the groundwork. This code is in C#, but for one it's no problem to mix-and-match with VB, and it's not really that hard to port. Do pay attention to the various parameters controlling the hash algorithm used etc. Here's the link to the code that claims to do this at least to some extent. It should suffice to get you started: https://github.com/medo64/Medo/blob/main/src/Medo/Security/Cryptography/CryptPassword.cs and https://www.medo64.com/2013/03/crypt-compatible-password-generation-in-csharp/ . I have not verified or used the code, use it at your own discretion.